# Cannot use rpath for cross-compilation

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cross-compiling, rpath

*Continuation of [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67802480/up-many-issue-whil-cross-compiling-for-arm-linux-gnueabihf)*

First of all, I'm new on the site, excuse me if I make beginner mistakes :).

Then, my subject has been on the front page of many topics but I didn't really find any similarity or the topic is very old.

## Put in context:

I have a Linux Debian Jessie ARMhf tablet (gcc version 4.9.2)
I have a Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa x86_64 PC
I want to cross compile files from the PC to the tablet
The tablet is connected in SSH with the PC (so I can't do a "target" on the tablet)

## Problem description:

I am trying to compile a c++ file that depends on shared .so libraries.

**I would like to set the location of these libraries with -Wl,-rapth,/path/to/lib but it doesn't seem to work.**

The error must be related to the **arm-linux-gnueaihf-g++ compiler**.
Indeed when I do with the base pc compiler :

```
`$ g++ -o test test.cpp -Iinclude -Wl,-rpath,/path/to/my/lib -L/path/to/lib -lLib1name -lLib2name`
```

**there are no errors, but with the cross-compiler**

```
`$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ ...`
```

it indicates an error :

```
`$ /usr/local/lib/lLib1name.so file not recognized`
```

You can already see that it doesn't take into account -rpath (because the paths are different) and that arm-linux-gnueabihf should be the source of the error.

Thank you for helping me :)

###### Info :

- Problem n°8
- Starting on 18/06/2021
- Closed on --
- See the history of the [problems here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67802480/up-many-issue-whil-cross-compiling-for-arm-linux-gnueabihf)

Comment: Did you source the environment variable file provided by cross compiler?

Comment: Hi, I did not use this file, can you please explain in more detail ?

Comment: What if you add `-L/path/to/my/lib`?

Comment: Also, I suggest to stop maintaining this "list of problems" or whatever it is. Questions are supposed to be just questions, not lists of questions.

Comment: `-rpath` is for finding libraries at run time. The path will be used on the target machine and needs to point to the directory on the target machine where the libraries will reside. It has nothing to do with finding libraries when linking. The latter is the job of `-L`.

Comment: If your lib1 and lib2 are widely used library like pthread or soemthing else. -L part might be handled by a file you need to source before compile. Read your toolchain documentation about how to start.